# EXT drag and drop events clash - ie. how can I use both ondragout and notifyout at the same time?

Tags: javascript, extjs

So I've got multiple `Ext.dd.DragSource` and `Ext.dd.DropTarget` objects. To get the correct behaviour that I need I'm attaching logic to events on both these objects. Its not possible to just have all the logic attached to either drag or drop.

My problem is that when I set `onDragOut` and `onDragEnter` on the drag object they stop the `notifyEnter` and `notifyOut` from firing on the drop object.

Is there a way to allow for both of these events to fire?

```
var ds = new Ext.dd.DragSource(id, { ddGroup: 'drops' });
ds.onDragEnter = function (e, id) { console.log('Drag Enter'); }
ds.onDragOut = function (e, id) { console.log('Drag Exit'); }

var dt = new Ext.dd.DropTarget(id, { ddGroup: 'drops' });
// These never fire.
dt.notifyEnter = function (source, evt, data) { console.log('Drop Enter'); }
dt.notifyOut = function (source, evt, data) { console.log('Drop Exit'); }
```

I'm using Extjs 4.0.2a, and unfortunately am stuck with this version at the moment. Any help with this would be great.

Answer (score 0):

As there have been no answers I'll just add the work around that I'm currently using. It's not a solution to the problem, just an alternative to side step the issue.

So, as I can not get both those events firing on the drag and drop elements at the same time, I'm simply using different events.

```
var ds = new Ext.dd.DragSource(id, { ddGroup: 'drops' });
ds.onDragOver = function (e, id) { console.log('Drag Over'); }
ds.beforeDragOut = function (e, id) { console.log('Drag Out Almost'); }
```

Even though these events are not quite the same as what I wanted, with a little extra logic I can get them to act in a very similar way.

If there is a better solution, a way to fire the proper events, then I'll happily accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the ExtJS docs and source code, I think you're overwriting `onDragEnter` and `onDragOut`, where the original functions will trigger the calls to `notifyEnter` and `notifyOut`. I would suggest only overwriting functions listed in the docs (http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.dd.DragSource) as "an empty function by default", e.g., `beforeDragEnter` and `beforeDragOut`.

If you really have to have those methods overwritten, I would recommend saving the originals and invoking them from your functions. If you want help with that pattern I can edit my answer to provide an example.